# How do you interpret this SEM image?

Tags: microscopy

[[image: SEM image of paper sheet]]can you help us in interpreting this image?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2uIp.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/746300/2451

Comment: Hi Christine Faith Cabrera. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.